# HasManyThrough vs HasAndBelongsToMany

Tags: loopbackjs

What is the diff between these HasManyThrough vs HasAndBelongsToMany ??

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasManyThrough+relations

VS

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasAndBelongsToMany+relations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer lies in the relation name itself. I'm going to use examples provided in the documentation.

**HasManyThrough**:

- physician hasMany patients through appointment
- patient hasMany physician through appointment

  Here, both physicians and patients are related to each other through appointments but are not directly related. appointment model is helping to create a relation as it belongs to both physician and patient. Because of appointment, a patient can book an appointment to as many physicians. And a physician can see as many patients who booked him/her.

**HasAndBelongsToMany**:

- student has many classes and belongs to many classes.
- classes has many students and belongs to many student.

  Here, both students and classes are related to each other directly. students generally attend many classes like physics, chemistry etc - so they have many classes. And since attendance is taken in each class, therefore students belong to many classes. 
  Likewise, a class is attended by many students - so class have many students. And since attendance is maintained for each student, therefore class belong to many students.

**Note:**

1. if two classes are related with many-to-many relationship through an intervening model like appointment, then use hasManyThrough.
2. if two classes are directly related with many-to-many relationship, use hasAndBelongsToMany

Comment: Well explained, Bravo!

Comment: Both relations require join tables, right? What are the implementation differences?

Answer (score 2):

`hasManyThrough` is just a `hasMany` relation for which a through model has been defined. See `params.through` in https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/4c9e91423f3d356bb544790075dcb7f891450096/lib/relation-definition.js#L659.

`hasAndBelongsToMany` is essentially a shortcut to set a `hasManyThrough` relation on both sides. If a `through` model has not been defined it just concatenates both model names and tries to find a model by that name, if that fails it just tries to fetch relations from a table by that name (https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/blob/4c9e91423f3d356bb544790075dcb7f891450096/lib/relation-definition.js#L1630).

If you define a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relation between `Assembly` and `Part`, it will set a `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relations between `Assembly` and `AssemblyPart` and also another pair of them between Part and AssemblyPart. If `AssemblyPart` model is not defined, it will just try to use a table (or collection I guess if MongoDB, I'm mostly a RDBMS guy) named `assemblypart`. It will also define a `hasManyThrough` relation from `Assembly` to `Part` using `AssemblyPart` as the through Model (so that `assembly.parts` is available) and its counterpart from `Part` to `Assembly` (`part.assemblies`).

What I'm trying to say is that you can achieve exactly the same as `hasAndBelongsToMany` by manually defining an `AssemblyPart` model with the corresponding `hasMany` and `belongsTo` to both `Assembly` and `Part` models and the two `hasManyThrough`: from `Assembly` to `Part` and from `Part` to `Assembly`.